# ObjectMapper or HttpServletRequest not configured in default AuthApi interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven-plugin

I have created application https://github.com/kulkarnipradnyas/cultfit/tree/main/auth-service where payload and interfaces i have created through open api maven plugin

```xml
<groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
<artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${swagger.codegen.maven.plugin.version}</version>
```

https://github.com/kulkarnipradnyas/cultfit/tree/main/swagger
when i try to hit my /auth/signup endpoint on postman, it is giving warning "ObjectMapper or HttpServletRequest not configured in default AuthApi interface." It is not letting my endpoint work.Can someone help me with all possible problems and if it is known problem what is the solution.(I am new to springboot) attaching generated interface and my controller

```
@RestController
@Validated
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class AuthController implements AuthApi {

    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;

    public AuthController() {
    }

    @Override
    @PostMapping("/auth/signIn")
     public   ResponseEntity<Void> signIn(String xCorrelationID,String xRequestID){
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }
    @Override
    @PostMapping("/auth/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> signupUser(@RequestBody User user){
           String token = authService.register(user);
            return new ResponseEntity(token,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

generated AuthAPI has below method:

```
  @RequestMapping(
        value = {"/auth/signup"},
        produces = {"application/json"},
        consumes = {"application/json"},
        method = {RequestMethod.POST}
    )
    default ResponseEntity<Void> signupUser(@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.DEFAULT,description = "Create User",required = true,schema = @Schema) @RequestBody @Valid User body) {
        if (!this.getObjectMapper().isPresent() || !this.getAcceptHeader().isPresent()) {
            log.warn("ObjectMapper or HttpServletRequest not configured in default AuthApi interface so no example is generated");
        }

        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }
}
ServiceConfig:
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends  
   WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {  
 it has below method
@Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) ->
                    //authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()
                    authorize
                            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, 
        "/auth/signup").permitAll()
                             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, 
      "/auth/signIn").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            ) .exceptionHandling(exception -> 
  exception.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint))
            .sessionManagement(session -> 
  session.sessionCreationPolicy 
      (SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

}
```

Comment: Needs code instead of images in the question.

Comment: i was trying to edit  my post somehow its locked and restricting edits

Comment: I can edit it just fine, you should be able to as well. I unflagged it just in case.

Comment: tried 5 times, giving error "there are too many pending edits on stackoverflow.Please try again"

Comment: Then accept or decline the pending changes.

Comment: When you receive the message "There are too many pending edits", it means that there are already a lot of suggested edits waiting for review and your edit has been added to the queue. You will need to wait until some of the suggested edits have been reviewed and approved before you can submit another edit.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346511/how-can-i-see-all-my-pending-reviews

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252047/discussion-between-pradnya-kulkarni-and-h3ar7b3a7).

Answer (score 0):

I have invalidated cache from intelijj and it started working.The warning it was throwing through default method written in implemented interface.
If anyone come across such issue below are check points:
1.Import module properly in pom.xml
2.Download maven dependencies after adding new module.
3.Name and parameter written in interface should be same to override method in controller.